# Trying to pass data from ListView to another class

Tags: java, android, android-listview

So I've been stuck on this for hours.  I'm trying to setup an async task that will load up an images for my listview in another class and I'm passing information that gives me an error

Any help would be appreciated!

public class TheResults extends Activity {

```
public static final String DEFAULTNAME = "DefaultFile";
private GETTHEIMAGE imgFetch;
private ArrayList<Item_Info> Info = new ArrayList<Item_Info>();

String Data = null;
String THESTRING = null;
TextView httpStuff;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.theresults);

    SharedPreferences Search = getSharedPreferences(DEFAULTNAME, 0);
    Data = Search.getString("THERESULTS", null);
    GetINFO();
    populatelist();
}

private void GetINFO() {
    }
    }
}

private void populatelist() {
    ArrayAdapter<Item_Info> adapter = new TheListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listings);
    list.findFocus();
    list.getWindowToken();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class TheListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item_Info> {
    public TheListAdapter() {
        super(TheResults.this, R.layout.items, Info);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View item_View = convertView;
        ImageHolder holder = null;

        if (item_View == null) {
            item_View = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
            Item_Info CurrentItem = Info.get(position);
            holder = new ImageHolder();
            holder.ICON_IMG = (ImageView)item_View.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
            holder.ICON_IMG.setTag(CurrentItem.getItemPIC());
            Drawable MYIMG = imgFetch.GetTheImagedata(this, holder.ICON_IMG);

            holder.ICON_TITLE = (TextView)item_View.findViewById(R.id.icon_title);
            holder.ICON_TITLE.setText(CurrentItem.getItemTITLE());

            holder.ICON_LOCATION = (TextView)item_View.findViewById(R.id.icon_location);
            holder.ICON_LOCATION.setText(CurrentItem.getItemLOCATION());

            holder.ICON_PRICE = (TextView)item_View.findViewById(R.id.icon_price);
            if (CurrentItem.getItemPRICE() == null) {
                holder.ICON_PRICE.setText(CurrentItem.getItemPRICE());
                holder.ICON_PRICE.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tempbg);
            } else {
                holder.ICON_PRICE.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pricebg);
                holder.ICON_PRICE.setText(CurrentItem.getItemPRICE());
            }

            holder.ICON_DATE = (TextView)item_View.findViewById(R.id.icon_date);
            holder.ICON_DATE.setText(CurrentItem.getItemLOCATION());
        }else{
            holder = (ImageHolder)item_View.getTag();
        }
        return item_View;
    }
}
static class ImageHolder{
    ImageView ICON_IMG;
    TextView ICON_TITLE;
    TextView ICON_LOCATION;
    TextView ICON_PRICE;
    TextView ICON_DATE;
}
```

}

Comment: You aren't going to post the error?

Comment: "gives me an error".... Seriously? You won't get a lot of quality help with so many informations..

Comment: sorry this is what logcat is showing

Comment: What is at line 178 of `TheResults`?

Comment: Drawable MYIMG = imgFetch.GetTheImagedata(this, holder.ICON_IMG);

Comment: What is `imgFetch`? It doesn't appear to be initialized

Comment: A reference to another class or is this a `static` reference? Where do you initialize it?

Comment: I did initialize it gonna clean up my post to show it

Comment: I did it in another class so you're saying I should set it where the ListAdapter is set.

Comment: Yes. If you initialized it in another class and created a reference to it then that reference was destroyed when the other class was. See my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the logcat after the line

```
06-21 19:15:06.887: E/AndroidRuntime(11408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

is the exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

which tells us that something is `null` and that is throwing the exception. If we look for the first line of the code that references your project we will see where the problem occurs. Here, it happens to be the next line in logcat

```
at com.clistc.TheResults$TheListAdapter.getView(TheResults.java:178)
```

Which tells us that the line is 178 of `TheResults.java` and that it is inside the `getView()` method. We have established that it is this line

```
Drawable MYIMG = imgFetch.GetTheImagedata(this, holder.ICON_IMG);
```

which means that `imgFetch` is probably `null` and you try to call a function on it which returns `null` since the variable is `null`. I don't know what that variable is but it isn't being initialized before this line

**Edit**

`imgFetch` isn't initialized anywhere. It is declared here

```
private GETTHEIMAGE imgFetch;
```

but you never initialize it by giving it a value. You need to do something like

```
private GETTHEIMAGE imgFetch = new GETTHEIMAGE();
```

assuming it has an empty constructor

Comment: Ok I've been trying to understand logcat for a while now and you really helped me out thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It is hard to understand until you see how to read it. Then debugging is a whole lot easier